# Cassandra-Driver webpack BREAKING CHANGE in React to access datastaxdb

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, cassandra

I have a react app and have been installing packages using npm. I have a datastax db that I am trying to access in my react scripts using cassandra-driver, and make requests from using axios. I ran "npm install cassandra-driver" successfully. The line

```
const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
```

Throws 23 errors. All errors are breaking changes of the webpack version not including polyfills for node.js core modules by default. Such as

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cassandra-driver/lib/streams.js 23:4-21
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\Base\Documents\py1\node_modules\cassandra-driver\lib'
```

Other posts about the webpack polyfill problems instruct to alter items in the webpack.config file. My problem is I don't know where to find the webpack config file as in my node_modules there are several files and a folder named webpack, and I am not new to programming but I am new to webdev & react. If there is an alternate solution for connecting my scripts to datastax that would be helpful as well. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

OK I realize my error. I'm trying to access the db from the client side, and cassandra-driver is designed for server-side.